# early morning and late afternoon emails

Tags: email, time-management, work-time, overtime

I've recently read an article about how the successful managers don't read emails first thing in the morning. The question I have is very general. How to handle the work emails you receive (mostly from co-workers and managers) at very early mornings or at night - basically outside working hours? Shall I check my emails late at nights - or early in the mornings? what does a senior person ideally do? What is the professional time during the day to answer non-urgent emails? I personally hate making "free overtime" a culture for my team.

Comment: This depends completely on the company culture. Some places you are expected to be "always on", while others not so much.

Comment: That is pretty silly advice.  Only a very senioer manager could get away with it. You should not check emails outside work hours unless you are on call or there is something urgent going on.

Comment: I would like to agree with HLGEM but "People" make such things a culture. especially when it's "free"

Comment: [This](http://www.fastcompany.com/3000619/what-successful-people-do-first-hour-their-work-day) is what I read in TheFastCompany but there are actually tons of [books](http://www.amazon.com/Never-Check-E-Mail-Morning-Unexpected/dp/0743250885) and [articles](http://sidsavara.com/personal-development/do-not-check-email-in-the-morning) on the net about emails in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally hate the idea the there is one overriding rule for email response and time of day checking.  I honestly believe that when you check email, how you respond, and the timeliness of your response is entirely a case by case thing, and it has to fit with your work mission, your organization's culture and your personal style.  I know a lot of successful managers who read email first thing in the morning - in particular because that is the morning ritual for how they start their day, and morning is the time when they focus on incoming messages.

But I agree that it has to be a conscious decision and *how* a manager manages their email responses is a fairly useful way for setting a tone in a team.

Here's some things to think about:

**Email Outside of Working Hours**

How and when a boss responds to email should and does impact the perception of what's expected and acceptable.  I'm a fan of leading by example, and I'd advocate to anyone in a management position to consider how they want the team to function when they check and respond to email after hours.

As the boss - it's not unusual that the first round of urgent email will your desk first and it's your opportunity to triage.  If your team has a mission critical function that will fail if you don't respond ASAP to a high priority incident, then you're just going to have to check email after hours and you're going to have to expect that your people will be responsive when you ask.  That's not to say that you may not expect that a person spending a few hours working on an issue in the evening won't also take some time later in the week to balance out life and family commitments.

Things I generally do, and have done across a few positions:

- Check email in the evening, but often just the subject and sender - particularly in technical work, there's plenty of auto-generated email that can be ignored in this way.  These days, the awesomeness of most phone email checking is that I can see at a glance if the number of mails in my inbox has changed, which can mean that I'm only checking when I see the number change.
- Pick up on urgent mail, and stop the chain of email - if it's REALLY urgent, why not call?  Email has a general expectation of passivity and time delay that is the opposite of what you want in a crisis.  First call the person who sent the mail, and verify that it's worth kicking into high gear.  Then start calling your people to mobilize the crisis fighting squad.
- It can be useful to do both - written detail is good in email, notification in a non-time-delay basis is good with phone calls.  So if you need someone to do something with a lot of detailed info, send it then call them.
- If this occurs frequently, consider on call rotations or formalizing staggered work hours.  Mission critical is mission critical and there are plenty of team models to cover this.  That's a good way to segue into having this discussion with upper management - if you are handling a number of urgent issues each month, it's fair to say "we need to change how we do business".

Don't mail if you're at home with your family and it's NOT urgent.  If what you are trying to do is to get ahead a bit because you're balancing some work and family commitments, then figure out a way to stack it in your outbox and actually send it in the morning - particularly, if you are sending to subordinates.

**Working with Variations in Work Hours**

The other reason for off hours email is that people don't work the same hours.  Whether it's variations in work hours in a single time zone, or just the difference between time zones - it's fair in the modern office to expect that different people are in the office during different hours - and email is the perfect medium for working with that variation.

In a given team in a given location, it's fair to set the tone for "between the hours of X and Y, let's try to be timely" - that's the general idea of core hours.  From there - make the time zones work your favor - don't stress to compose an email first thing in the morning, if it won't get read until that evening.  Realize that you, too, have a pace to your work day and you can maximize your own energy by finding a reliable rhythm to how you respond.

I've noticed that most offices will take into account the boss' rhythm for email, if it's reliable - if they know the boss always checks and responds to email in a certain window, people will often make the effort to get him what he wants and needs by that time.

**Focus on connecting speed of response to importance of response**

There's no such thing as having enough time for all your email.  Focus your time on making sure that the most important decisions and responses are sent as quickly as possible.  Make it clear with your folks what acceptable response rates are and don't feel bad about the fact that timing works differently on both sides of the power-dynamic.  I used to feel awful that I'd need information within minutes or hours, but couldn't often give an update back to my team faster than a couple days.  But the thing is - bosses have a different set of work than the people that report to them.

Subtle things to be aware of:

- Apologize when you know you are later than you should be
- Don't hesitate to give deadlines and scope the work of the response.  For example "I need an estimate on that by noon, just a quick guess on the time is fine, I don't need you to spend more than a few minutes pondering this.  But if you could do some research and confirm your estimate by the day after tomorrow, that would be ideal."
- Follow up and give feedback when important deadlines aren't met.
- Find a way to communicate the difference between important and less important.

**Perfect time for non-urgent emails**

I'd say that that is when YOU have the time.  Realize that email is one of the lowest fidelity ways of communicating with people.   You'll get far more information out of talking in person, talking by video or phone, or even IMing (sometimes) than you will by email.  So in the workday, prioritize the more important/higher quality communications first - saving the non-urgent email for the times when the high quality communication isn't available.

Most managers I know have what I call "sanity time" - they have an intentional spot in the work day where they take time for themselves, for deep thinking, strategy and self-initiated work.  It's almost always early morning before people get in, or after the majority of folks leave.  Before or after your sanity time is probably the best place to bang out the last of the non-urgent stuff, since it's unlikely you'll be interrupted.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic bullet technique for being successful. Not reading emails first thing in the morning might work for some people, but it is likely causing all sorts of problems for others in their organizations.  I would also suspect it only works for people who have an executive assistant who will make sure to tell him if there is something critical he needs to see.

In many organizations, email is critical to knowing what the problems are that you are facing that day. I could not do my job if I didn't read emails first thing because the content might change not only my priorities but the priorities of my team. No one is successful if they don't know about urgent changes in priority or new problems that have cropped up.  I also get emails directly from clients and have performance goals concerning how quickly I must answer them.

Senior managers deal with bigger picture, less detail-oriented things and can get away with not looking until later or at a specific time of day. The people who actually have to do the work and their immediate bosses cannot.

I have also had senior bosses like that who ignore those things so long they create problems for their own staff but not telling tham about tasks that need to be done until they are almost due or over due. Then the tasks get done in a scamble and hence done less well than they could have been, and the staff gets stressed causing the best people to leave. So while they may appear to be successful by ignoring the trivia of email, often they would have been even more successful if they had handled things in a timely manner.

But to be successful, you have to work out the rhythm of your day **based on the way the work in your organization flows** not on some random managerarial article. If you have tight deadlines and frequent changes of direction, you cannot afford to not read emails as they come in. I have had many emails through the years telling me to stop working on something because it had been cancelled by the client or telling me that this new issues is a higher priority than what we are doing. I also get emails from my employees (who are not co-located with me or even inthe same time zone) when they run out of work to do (no point in wasting a whole day of production because you were too busy to read the emails). I get meeting requests in emails and it helps to know about meetings before you get a reminder that it is due to start as sometimes you need to prep for them. If you have workers in other time zones, you may come into meeting requests that are early in the day that you were not aware of when you left.

Now that said, it is often a good idea to know which emails to read and which ones can be handled later or ignored. You don't have to read every email in depth or change directino at every whim.